# Problema con la liberación de memoria dinamica

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo este código:

```
char* texto=(char*)malloc(11);//Retorno un arrays de 10 char
strcpy(texto,"Hello World");
texto[4]='\0';//Recortamos la cadena.
for (int i=5;i<11;i++)
 free(&texto[i]);//Liberamos el espacio que no nesecitamos.
```

Esto me detiene el ejecutable. Pero si hiciera esto:

```
texto[7]='\0';
for (int i=8;i<11;i++)
 free(&texto[i]);
```

El ejecutable finaliza perfectamente. ¿Porqué? y ¿Como lo soluciono?.

Conseguí esta página:
[tio C(GCC)](https://tio.run/##XY5BDoIwEEX3PUWDibSihq40KXXtHZQFlgKTlJbUEjXGs9cCK13@9@b/jNy1UoawAiP1WCtc3H2t4bbvTuiHgf1HDkw7MTAe9xUYQt9IdpXbYK@e3goyB9pXWltJGKMcxZIcXmT22@SsosEP63SdRDnTy6EU6TVPOWqsw2TaBnHkUDDGIcsowo1TiqyXYyhjb4iP@GYZjRE55UdncM7RJ4Qv) Hay pude ver este error:

```
double free or corruption (top)
/srv/wrappers/c-gcc: line 5:  3868 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./.bin.tio "$@" < .input.tio
```

¿Pero porque si estoy liberando memoria que reserve para recortar la cadena?.
Alguna ayuda o consejo. La idea es solamente recortar la cadena y liberar el espacio que no necesito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La gestión de memoria no funciona como tú crees. Cuando pides memoria:

```
char* texto=(char*)malloc(11);
//    ^^^^^ <---- Bloque de 11 char:
/*

              | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
texto ------> |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
*/
```

Pides un bloque entero de memoria, este bloque es apuntado por el retorno de `malloc` y se refiere a ese bloque de 11 caracteres. Toda memoria pedida por `malloc` debe ser liberada por `free` y lo que has pedido con `malloc` es ese bloque de 11 caracteres, así que no puedes liberar parte de ellos de la misma manera que si compras una barra de pan, no puedes devolver la mitad de ella ¡haber comprado media!

[image]

Sin embargo, puedes **realojar** la memoria, para eso se usa la función [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc):

```
char* texto=(char*)malloc(11);//Retorno un arrays de 10 char
strcpy(texto,"Hello World");
texto[4]='\0';//Recortamos la cadena.
texto = realloc(texto, 5);//descartamos de la sexta posición en adelante.
```

Comment: Es dificil superar una barra de pan en una respuesta....